# Validate data before AJAX call gets fired

Tags: jquery, ajax, click, validation

I'm trying to validate data (with http://formvalidator.net/) before the AJAX call gets executed. But because I have 2 submit buttons, 1 for add and 1 for edit, I can't find the right syntax. Sofar I have the following code:

```
function validate_resource_form () {
    $.validate({
        form: '#resource_form',
        modules: 'date, security, location, file',
        onModulesLoaded: function() {
            $('input[name="country"]').suggestCountry();
        },
        onError: function() {
            alert('You have not answered all required fields');
        },
        onValidate : function() {
            if ($("#add_resource").click()){
                create_resource ();
            } else if ($("#edit_resource").click()){
                update_resource ();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This code only execute the first if statement. In this case it wil only create a new resource when you click the add_resource or edit_resource button. How can I validate the data and then fire the right function based on the button that has been clicked?

Answer (score 2):

```
 function validate_resource_form () {
    $.validate({
        form: '#resource_form',
        modules: 'date, security, location, file',
        onModulesLoaded: function() {
            $('input[name="country"]').suggestCountry();
        },
        onError: function() {
            alert('You have not answered all required fields');
        },
        onValidate : function() {              
          $("input").click(function(e){
            var idClicked = e.target.id;
            if ( idClicked  == "#add_resource"){
              create_resource ();
            } else if ( idClicked  == "#edit_resource"){
              update_resource ();
            }
         });

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with this code you can add a hidden input

```
<input type='hidden' id='clickedAction'>
```

then update your submit button to

```
<button onclick='$("#clickedAction").val("c")' id="add_resource">create</button> 
<button onclick='$("#clickedAction").val("u")' id='edit_resource'>update</button>
```

c mean create u update

then change onValidate to :

```
  onValidate : function() {
        if ($("#clickedAction").val()=='c'){
            create_resource ();
        } else if ($("#clickedAction").val()=='u'){
            update_resource ();
        }
    }
```